# Have grep display errors only

Tags: bash, macos, grep, macos-sierra, errorlevel

I am using macOS Sierra, which has bash version 3.2.57(1)-release. I want verify checksums of files using `shasum -c /files.txt > /out.txt`, where `files.txt` contains the checksums and `out.txt` is where the results are saved.

What I want to do is use grep in some way to filter out and only save the errors to `out.txt`. How possible is this? Could `$?` come in handy for this?

Thanks

---

**Additional info:**

```
--BEGIN /file.txt CONTENTS--
865f34fe7ba81e1337ddbdfc511547d190367bbf3dad21aeb6da3eec621044f5  /samplefile.good
93ddaab2f672ff976756f50677646cafebabe93244f615e687db01399cf3fbc6  /samplefile.bad

--END /file.txt CONTENTS--


--BEGIN USER INTERACTION--

$ shasum -c file.txt
/samplefile.good: OK
/samplefile.bad: FAILED
shasum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

$ shasum -c file.txt 2> errors.txt
/samplefile.good: OK
/samplefile.bad: FAILED

$ cat errors.txt
shasum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

$ shasum -c file.txt 2>&1 > errors.txt
shasum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

$ cat errors.txt
/samplefile.good: OK
/samplefile.bad: FAILED

--END USER INTERACTION--
```

This is what I want to have:

```
$ cat errors.txt
/samplefile.bad: FAILED
```

or

```
$ cat errors.txt
/samplefile.bad: FAILED
shasum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly seem what I'm looking for, but I can still give it a shot. I just want to have `grep`, or something similar, filter out only the errors `shasum` outputs.

Comment: If errors are written to `stderr`, then `2> out.txt` should suffice.  (`/out.txt` will probably get `Permission denied`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `grep` to get all kinds of errors from the `shasum` command :

```
$ shasum -c file.txt 2> errors.txt
$ cat error.txt 
shasum: file.txt: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found
```

But if you really want to catch some kinds of errors, you can indeed use `grep` like that :

```
$ shasum -c file.txt 2>&1 | grep -i "no properly formatted" > errors.txt
```

Comment: `shasum -c file.txt 2>&1 | ...`. And if you want **only** errors, `2>&1 >/dev/null`.

Comment: @PesaThe +1 my bad ! (i've updated my answer, thanks)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get the right errors saved to `errors.txt`. [See this pastebin paste for more info](https://pastebin.com/DV2MECN7), since SE comments are never nicely formatted.

Comment: @leetbacoon edit your question and include desired output.

Comment: @PesaThe Edited the question.

Comment: @leetbacoon Well, use the second solution and change the `grep` to `grep FAILED > errors.txt `. That should do it. You can also omit the `2>$1` in that case.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I have a file that contains the word `FAILED` in it? And it passes?

Comment: @leetbacoon if that's the case, use `grep 'FAILED$'`. That will only match the word `FAILED` at the end of a line.

Comment: Hey, just thought of this. What about `shasum -c file.txt | grep -v ": OK$"`?

Comment: @leetbacoon that will do too.